# What's a zip join? Have you ever heard of that, or a pairwise join?

Tags: sql, database, scala, slick

[This section of Slick's documentation page](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#joining-and-zipping) is quite odd.

What is this zip join? It says that it means:

> a pairwise join of two queries

but what that means @.@ I don't know

I've tried Googling for both "zip join" and "pairwise join"... but no results to do with databases.

I do get [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_disjoint) from Wikipedia when I search on "pairwise" though...

Could somebody give me some examples illustrating the differences between a zip join and a normal outer or inner join? Thanks!

Comment: no formal idea - but this would imply to me the first row of query A goes with the first row of query B etc.

Comment: I'd agree think about a zipper.  order of data in the joined sets is important thus 1st row to 1st row 2nd row to 2nd row etc.  **The resulting zipped query, however, can be represented in SQL with the use of a row number function, so zipWithIndex is supported as a primitive operator:** implying that the zipper concept is spot on and that order of the sets is VERY important

Comment: Maybe they mean a "Sort Merge Join": http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/sort-merge-join

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zip joins are only meaningful when talking about ordered sets.  Instead of joining based on the value of a column, you are joining based on the row number.

Table1

```
[λ]  [color] 
400  violet 
415  indigo 
475  blue   
510  green  
570  yellow 
590  orange 
650  red
```

Table2

```
[flame]  [element]
green    boron
yellow   sodium
white    magnesium
red      calcium
blue     indium
```

**Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON [color] = [flame]** : only matching rows

```
[λ]  [color]  [flame]  [element]
475  blue     blue     indium 
510  green    green    boron
570  yellow   yellow   sodium
650  red      red      calcium
```

**Table1 OUTER JOIN Table2 ON [color] = [flame]** : all rows, matched where possible

```
[λ]  [color]  [flame]  [element]
400  violet   NULL     NULL
415  indigo   NULL     NULL
475  blue     blue     indium
510  green    green    boron
570  yellow   yellow   sodium
590  orange   NULL     NULL
650  red      red      calcium
NULL NULL     white    magnesium
```

**Table1 "zip joined" to Table2** : all rows, regardless of match

```
[λ]  [color]  [flame]  [element]
400  violet   green    boron
415  indigo   yellow   sodium
475  blue     white    magnesium
510  green    red      calcium
570  yellow   blue     indium
590  orange   NULL     NULL
650  red      NULL     NULL
```

Zip joins are combining the data like a zipper, pairing the first row from one table with the first row from the other, second paired with second, etc.  It's not actually looking at that data.  They can be generated very quickly, but they won't mean anything unless there is some meaningful order already present in your data or if you just want to generate random pairings

Comment: Nice explanation. Slick's zip method is corresponding to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike@zip[B](GenIterable[B]):Iterable[(A,B)] which is documented as " Returns a iterable collection formed from this iterable collection and another iterable collection by combining corresponding elements in pairs.".

Comment: How is it implemented? What SQL is generated?