# How to implement a ZIP JOIN in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let say I have table #Foo:

```
Id Color
-- ----
1  Red
2  Green
3  Blue
4  NULL
```

And table #Bar:

```
Value
-----
1
2.5
```

I would like to create table Result using simple statement to get:

```
Id Color   Value
-- ----   -----
1  Red    1
2  Green  2.5
3  Blue   NULL
4  NULL   NULL
```

What I have invented so far is:

```
WITH cte1
AS
(
    SELECT [Id], [Color], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS 'No'
    FROM #Foo
),
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT [Value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS 'No'
    FROM #Bar
)
SELECT [Id], [Color], [Value]
FROM cte1 c1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.[No] = c2.[No]
```

Do you know faster or more standard way to do ZIP JOIN in T-SQL?

Comment: Your solution is the way I should have done it.

Comment: `ZIP JOIN`? What is that?

Comment: @ypercube http://stackoverflow.com/a/17581681/2042090

Comment: This seems like a join with fairly narrow applicability due to the relational model requiring that row order should generally not be meaningful to the relations.  I wouldn't expect you to find anything faster.  If it's performance you're after it would probably be faster to generate two ordered result sets from two queries and then handle the "join" in your application by looping through the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id, Value FROM #Bar
)
SELECT F.Id, F.Color, CTE.Value
FROM #Foo F
LEFT JOIN CTE ON CTE.Id = F.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (pk_id int identity(1,1), Id INT, Color VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @Bar TABLE (pk_id int identity(1,1), Value DECIMAL(2, 1))

INSERT INTO @Foo (Id, Color)
VALUES (1, 'Red'), (2, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (4, NULL)

INSERT INTO @Bar (Value)
VALUES (1), (2.5);

SELECT F.id, F.Color, B.Value
FROM @Foo F
    LEFT JOIN @Bar B ON F.pk_id = B.pk_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `the CTE` or make your `query shorter`

with subquery's like this

```
select Id,Color,Value from 
(
    SELECT [Id], [Color], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS 'No'
    FROM #Foo
)x full outer join 
(
    SELECT [Value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS 'No'
    FROM #Bar
)y
on x.No=y.No
```

Comment: It is "more optimized" because you changed the join type. CTEs are always inlined by the query optimizer like you manually did.

Comment: They need `FULL` join though, not `LEFT`.

Comment: oopss!! yes they both the same ! perhaps this is shorter ?

Comment: I believe I'm a bigger fan of the CTE version, that's more readable to me imo

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice? (Admittedly, I may be miss-interpreting the question)

```
SELECT
  F.ID AS ID,
  F.Color AS Color,
  B.Value AS Value
FROM #Foo F
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #Bar B ON F.ID = FLOOR(B.Value)

--this DOES seem to return the correct output, but I'm not sure that my logic
--is what you are after
SELECT
  F.ID AS ID,
  F.Color AS Color,
  B.Value AS Value
FROM 
    (
      VALUES
        (1,'Red'),(2,'Green'),(3,'Blue'),(4, NULL)
    ) AS F(ID, Color)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
      VALUES    
        (1), (2.5)
    ) AS B(Value) 
  ON F.ID = FLOOR(B.Value)
```

Or are you wanting to essentially:

- Sort #Foo by ID
- Sort #Boo by Value
- Match:

  - "First" row from #Foo with "First" row from #Bar
  - "Second" row from #Foo with "Second" row from #Bar
  - etc...

(Sorry, but I am not familiar with what a "ZIP JOIN" is. 
I will look at the link provided by @RszardDzegan, though.)

Comment: What I need is to glue two tables together regardless of their values. Assume, that have two result sets and want to create one, uniform table by setting them together as follows: B first row next to A first row, B second row next to A second row etc. Values are irrelevant in such scenario. Just looking for an easy solution in SQL.

Comment: In that case, I believe that your solution with the CTE's is likely your best bet, just mind performance.
I'm a HUGE fan of CTE's and use them anywhere I can find reason to, BUT I have had performance issues when the result sets of the CTE's returned a large amount of data. 
"Large" usually means hundred MB's or so.

The only other concern would be, when dealing with a "set" of data, what EXACTLY does "first row" and "second row" , etc... mean?
Assuming there exists SOME column that rows can logically sort on, an additional consideration would be what to do with "ties".

FANTASTIC QUESTION!!

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (Id INT, Color VARCHAR(10));
DECLARE @Bar TABLE (Value DECIMAL(2, 1))

INSERT INTO @Foo (Id, Color)
VALUES (1, 'Red'), (2, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (4, NULL)

INSERT INTO @Bar (Value)
VALUES (1), (2.5);

WITH ECROSS
AS (
    SELECT F.Id, F.Color, B.Value, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY F.Id
            ) AS No1, DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY B.Value
            ) AS No2
    FROM @Foo F, @Bar B
    )
SELECT A.id, A.Color, B.Value
FROM ECROSS A
LEFT JOIN ECROSS B ON A.No1 = B.No2
    AND A.No1 = B.No1
GROUP BY A.id, A.Color, B.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You just need to provide both data types in the same structure with a row number per group. With that you can use the PIVOT operator to produce the expected result.

```
WITH 
CTE_FOO AS
(
   SELECT
       [Group]
      ,[Spread]
      ,[Aggregate]
   FROM 
      (VALUES
          (1, 1, N'Red'  )
         ,(2, 1, N'Green')
         ,(3, 1, N'Blue' )
         ,(4, 1, NULL    )
      ) AS FOO([Group], [Spread], [Aggregate])
),
CTE_BAR AS
(
   SELECT
       [Group]
      ,[Spread]
      ,CAST([Aggregate] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [Aggregate]
   FROM 
      (VALUES
          (1, 2, 1   )
         ,(2, 2, 2.5 )
      ) AS BAR([Group], [Spread], [Aggregate])
),
CTE_FOOBAR AS
(
   SELECT [Group], [Spread], [Aggregate] FROM CTE_FOO
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Group], [Spread], [Aggregate] FROM CTE_BAR   
)
SELECT 
    [Group] AS [ID]
   ,[1]     AS [Color]
   ,[2]     AS [Value]
FROM
    CTE_FOOBAR
PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Aggregate]) FOR [Spread] IN ([1], [2])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You  can skip creating new row numbers for #Foo, since its row numbers in this case are given.

Then the solution will become

```
SELECT F.Id,F.Color,newBar.Value from #Foo as F
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [Value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) AS 'No'
    FROM #Bar
) newBar
on F.Id=newBar.No
```

This solution has been tested and proven. It gives you all values of #Foo and for each a sorted value of #Bar if there is one.

Comment: I agree that in this particular case, the [Id] column acts as a row number, but it is not the crux. I'm looking for a general solution.