# How to get a combined/merged table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two views whose output is given as :

View1:

```
   --------------
   |users|branch|
   |  1  | A    |
   |  1  | B    |
   |  2  | A    |
   -------------
```

View2:

```
   --------------
   |users| Page |
   |  1  | P    |
   |  1  | Q    |
   |  1  | R    |
   |  2  | S    |
   |  2  | R    |
   -------------
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
   ----------------------
   |users| Page | Branch|
   |  1  | P    |  A    |
   |  1  | Q    |  B    |
   |  1  | R    | Null  |
   |  2  | S    |  A    |
   |  2  | R    | Null  |
   ---------------------
```

I am using SQLServer 2012.

Comment: That looks like a [zip join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263150/how-to-implement-a-zip-join-in-t-sql) to me, which is an uncommon way to join marginally related data without getting a partial Cartesian product (cross join).

Comment: i tried inner join for both views but the result wasn't as desired.  I want to display users with distinct page and branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work using a common zip join method:

```
;with view1_numbered as (
        select users,
            row_number() over (partition by users order by branch) num,
            branch
        from view1),
    view2_numbered as (
        select users
            row_number() over (partition by users order by page) num,
            page
        from view2
    )
select coalesce(v1.users,v2.users) users,
    v1.branch,
    v2.page
from view1_numbered v1
full outer join view2_numbered v2
    on  v2.users = v1.users
    and v2.num   = v1.num
order by coalesce(v1.users,v2.users), coalesce(v1.num,v2.num);
```

I used a FULL OUTER JOIN because there's no way to tell from here if there are always more branches than pages or vice-versa.

Comment: It worked! Just as I wanted. Thank you so much! :D