# SQL: Match Set of Approximate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, approximate

In my data set there are a set of numeric values to match to another equal sized set of values from another table where the "closest match" (without going over is desired:

```
Left   Right
A      M
B      N
C      O
D      P
```

So the goal is to join Left to Right, giving A M as the resulting row where A < M and M - A is the MINIMUM [M..P - A].

(Ignore that A..D and M..P might have more than one element with the same value.)

EDIT:  Similarly, B needs to match N, C to O, and D to P.

Tables would have multiple sets of such values, such that E..G would match Q..S but these would in a separate group on other fields not shown.

There might be many of these "sets" of matches (based on other fields in the table.

Suggestions or ideas? Preferable in T-SQL or basic SQL.

Comment: Appreciate help but since it wasn't clear:  B needs to match to N, C to O etc.

Not JUST the Max to Max.  But each in it's ordinal position, with many such sets in the same set of tables.  (Left and Right are merely to ask the question and in no way reflect real table names, L and R would have been better choices.

Comment: Are you talking about a [zip join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581414/whats-a-zip-join-have-you-ever-heard-of-that-or-a-pairwise-join)? Because that is different from what stated in the question after the data

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select l.*,
       (select max(r.right)
        from right r
        where r.right <= l.left
       ) as RightMatch
from left l;
```

Note:  this is just a sketch of the SQL.  `left` and `right` are (obviously) reserved words.  I'm just using them to match the naming conventions in your query.  You shouldn't use reserved words for column or table names.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `[left]` and `[right]` are on different table

```
SELECT l.Value, r.Value rValue
FROM   [LEFT] l
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 
                           Value
                    FROM   [Right] r
                    WHERE  l.value < r.value
                    ORDER BY Value) r
```

the minimum part of the formula is resolved by the `TOP 1` and the `ORDER BY`.

Using this query all the value A..D will match to M, as all of them are less them M and M is the closed to everyone of them, so probably the stated algorithm lack some rule.

---

In the case you want a zip join then one approach is to create a row number ordered by value and join by those numbers

```
WITH LID AS (
  SELECT Value
       , _ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
  FROM   [LEFT]
, RID AS (
  SELECT Value
       , _ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
  FROM   [RIGHT]
)
SELECT l.Value, r.Value
FROM   LID l
       INNER JOIN RID r ON LID._ID = RID._ID
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is available on SQLServer 2005 or better

Answer (score 0):

Best I have so far is to: Select the Max L(eft) with Max R(ight) of each set (e.g., A-M) into another table, delete that from original (a temp copy of) tables, and repeat until they are all matched up. This solution is very procedural -- probably not good SQL style.