# Zipping rows with the same "key" while joining tables

Tags: sqlite, join

I have two tables, one with objects, one with properties of the objects. Both tables have a personal ID and a date as "key", but since multiple orders of objects can be done by one person on a single day, it doesn't match well. I do know however, that the entries are entered in the same order in both tables, so it is possible to join on the order, if the personID and date are the same.

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
Table 1:
PersonID    Date        Object
1           20-08-2013  A
2           13-11-2013  B
2           13-11-2013  C
2           13-11-2013  D
3           21-11-2013  E

Table 2:
PersonID    Date        Property
4           05-05-2013  $           
1           20-08-2013  ^
2           13-11-2013  /
2           13-11-2013  *
2           13-11-2013  +
3           21-11-2013  &

Result:
PersonID    Date        Object  Property
4           05-05-2013          $
1           20-08-2013  A       ^
2           13-11-2013  B       /
2           13-11-2013  C       *
2           13-11-2013  D       +
3           21-11-2013  E       &
```

So what I want to do, is join the two tables and "zip" the group of entries that have the same (PersonID,Date) "key".

Something called "Slick" seems to have this [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581414/whats-a-zip-join-have-you-ever-heard-of-that-or-a-pairwise-join), but I'd like to do it in SQLite.

Any advice would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Why not just do a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables like

```
select t2.PersonID,
t2.Date,
t1.Object,
t2.Property
from table2 t2 
left join table1 t1 on t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID
order by t2.PersonID
```

Comment: Then I get all possible combinations of joining object with property for each (PersonID,Date) that is the same in both tables, instead of just a single one that works "horizontally" ([A,B,C] with [1,2,3] should give [(A,1),(B,2),(C,3)], not [[(A,1),(A,2),(A,3)],[(B,1),(B,2) etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Use a additional column to make every key unique in both tables. For example in SQLite you could use RowIDs to keep track of the order of insertion. To store this additional column in the database itself might be useful for other queries as well, but you do not have to store this.

First add the column ID to both tables, the DDL queries should now look like this: (make sure you do not add the primary key constraint until both tables are filled.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( 
    ID,
    PersonID,
    Date,
    Object 
);

CREATE TABLE table2 ( 
    ID,
    PersonID,
    Date,
    Property 
);
```

Now populate the ID column. You can adjust the ID to your liking. Make sure you do this for table2 as well:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET ID =( 
       SELECT table1.PersonID || '-' || table1.Date || '-' || count( * )
         FROM table1 tB
        WHERE table1.RowID >= tB.RowID 
              AND
              table1.PersonID == tB.PersonID 
              AND
              table1.Date == tB.Date 
   );
```

Now you can join them:

```
SELECT t2.PersonID,
   t2.Date,
   t1.Object,
   t2.Property
FROM table2 t2
   LEFT JOIN table1 t1
          ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```